# What does ImageDataGenerator returns, and how to do data augmentation?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to fit a CNN model (AlexNet architecture) with a 4900 images(480*640*3) dataset and I would like to do Data Augmentation, I have done a custom generator which use ImageDataGenerator method, because the images are on different paths and the labels too, so I have done a class who take all paths and save on two lists the images paths and its labels, then it loads on batches of 32 images and labels and fit the image data generator:

This is the method of the custom generator called from the model when it´s fit, and is where I fit the ImageDataGenerator

```
def __getitem__(self,index) :
      batch_x=self.img_filenames[index * self.batch_size : (index+1) * self.batch_size]
      batch_y=self.labels[index * self.batch_size: (index+1) * self.batch_size] 
      gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                         rotation_range=90,
                         brightness_range=(0.1,0.9),
                         horizontal_flip=True)
      X=[plt.imread(filename) for filename in batch_x]
      X,Y = next(gen.flow(x= np.array(X), y= np.array(batch_y), batch_size=self.batch_size))
      return X,Y
```

I have some questions:

What is supposed that ImageDataGenerator returns, if I pass 32(batch_size) differents images, it returns 32 modified images, 1 for each one, or 32 images for each one, and if I only pass 1 image with a batch size of 32, it returns 32 modified images from that one? I'm almost sure that are 1 for each one but I want to confirm.

Secondly, if I want to have 40k images, if I change the index to 0 again when it exceed samples//batch_size,and change the **len** method multiplying by 2 or whatever I want, it is supposed that as the images are generated randomly, I will have 4900 new images or as much as I want isn´t it?

The main problem is that when it reach 0.5 accuracy it stops increasing, I have tried with 3 epochs and it is the same, it increase till 3 or 4 batches and then stops, so that is why my doubts.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I printed X.shape and seems to be the 32 images but modified, so It doesn´t multiply the images. And the method to augment the data which I said works fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to answer
1. If you pass batch size 32 to `ImageDataGenerator` with `horizontal_flip=True` only, it flip all of 32 images horizontally and passes these 32 +32 (original + flipped) for training.
If you set `horizontal_flip` and `vertical_flip`, then 32+32+32 images will be passed for training. 
For `brightness_range` it produces one image for each brightness scale corresponding to one original image. It means if your brightness scale is `0.1-0.5`, then `32*5` images were produced.

I am not sure about the second question. A better choice is to do more data augmentation both on training and test data.

For third question, you should try `efficient net` with `focal loss`

Comment: But batches sizes must match with the steps_per_epoch, and I am using batch of 32, then with that modifications I would had been using batches of 32*10(brightness)*2(flip)*2?(rotation), then the steps_per_epochs is calculated with the lenght of the dataset(If I dont do the augmentation, and only use ImageDataGenerator) so there would be some data missing somewhere. Check this: [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/)

Comment: Check also the first example on keras preprocessing documentation: [link](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), on steps_per_epochs is using the length of the main trainning set, so the total images generated by the generator must match that length

Comment: `steps_per_epochs` is like how many steps needed to pass all batches of data, it should be like the number of sample (actual instead of augmented) divided by batch size.

Comment: for example, we have 100 images,  our batch size is 25, we need 4 steps to complete one epoch.  
now let do augmentation and say we have 500 images. our steps per epoch will `500/25=20` . we need 5 time more steps to complete one epoch, as data is 5 times augmented.

Comment: this happens in that case if we save all augmented images locally, but if we dont save them an use them in pipeline, then step per epoch will 4

Comment: but if my step size is 25, step per epoch is 4 ,and I pass 25 images to ImageDataGenerator, and I dont save them, then it won´t return more than 25 images, or should appear some type of error?